# Finding product count respect to old history with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good Evening there, hope everyone is fine and safe from Corona.
I have two Csv files. history.csv --> contain products and customerId, other CSV customers.csv contain all customerId present in history.csv. I want to find how many times a product is bought by each customer? For example:

```
product 3344 is bought 3 times by userID 2, product 3321 bought 1 time by userID 2.
```

i want to find for all users. below is my code, i'm not user it is correct or not.

```
get_count = pd.melt(part_with_no_count.set_index('customerId')['products'].apply(pd.Series).reset_index(),
                id_vars=['customerId'],
                value_name='products') \
        .dropna().drop(['variable'], axis=1) \
        .groupby(['customerId', 'products']) \
        .agg({'products': 'count'}) \
        .rename(columns={'products': 'product_count'}) \
        .reset_index() \
        .rename(columns={'products': 'productId'})
    get_count.to_csv("output/part_number_1_with_count.csv", index=False)
```

Sample data of history.csv:

```
products,customerId
27845,22986
39275,142175
43251,200540
42900,69496
21472,178294
37067,150285
4945,205945
17333,47461
38739,123967
46979,59203
436,105341
```

expected output(example):

```
customerId,productId,product_count
21,24186,1
28,25949,1
31,12962,1
31,26246,1
38,26683,1
43,1667,1
50,10831,1
54,47752,1
```

Comment: please show an example of your csv files and what would be your expected output

Comment: updated, please check.

Comment: can't upload my all data here, i can share you the data file if you want.

Comment: `df.groupby(['customerId'])['products'].count()` ? your code doesn't match the input - but all you need to do is an aggregation and count right?

Comment: I think you only need `df.groupby('customerId')['ProductId'].value_counts()`

Comment: please see the expected output example. @Datanovice

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @ansev , yes i can see output, but the column has no name can you give it a name ?
will it count product for each customer only? a product can be repeated for multiple customer

Comment: This counts how many times each customer bought each product. The name is product_count, see the answer: `.rename ('product_count').reset_index ()` at the end. `df.groupby('customerId')['ProductId'].value_counts().rename('product_count').reset_index()`. See answers section

Comment: @ansev sorry, it didn't scrolled down, got your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample df**

```
print(df)
    products  customerId
0      27845       22986
1      39275      142175
2      43251      200540
3      42900       69496
4      21472      178294
5      37067      150285
6       4945      205945
7      17333       47461
8      38739      123967
9      46979       59203
10       436      105341
```

---

**Solution**

```
df_count = (df.groupby('customerId')['products']
             .value_counts()
             .rename('product_count')
             .reset_index())
print(df_count)
    customerId  products  product_count
0        22986     27845              1
1        47461     17333              1
2        59203     46979              1
3        69496     42900              1
4       105341       436              1
5       123967     38739              1
6       142175     39275              1
7       150285     37067              1
8       178294     21472              1
9       200540     43251              1
```

where `df` is your `History` DataFrame.